# Minutes not quite in sync with seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timer which I am testing, it seems there is a bit of drift between when the minute countdown goes down by 1 and seconds whenever it reaches 59 seconds ()ie every minute:-

How can I alter this so they are both in sync?

my code is the following:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function now() {
    return window.performance ? window.performance.now() : Date.now();
  }

  function tick() {
    var timeRemaining = countdown - ((now() - initTick) / 1000);
    timeRemaining = timeRemaining >= 0 ? timeRemaining : 0;

    var countdownMinutes = Math.floor(timeRemaining / 60);
    var countdownSeconds = timeRemaining.toFixed() % 60;

    countdownTimer.innerHTML = countdownMinutes + ":" + countdownSeconds;

    if (countdownSeconds < 10) {
      countdownTimer.innerHTML = countdownMinutes + ":" + 0 + countdownSeconds;
    }

    if (timeRemaining > 0) {
      setTimeout(tick, delay);
    }
  }

  var countdown = 600; // time in seconds until user may login again
  var delay = 20; // time (in ms) per tick
  var initTick = now(); // timestamp (in ms) when script is initialized
  var countdownTimer = document.querySelector(".timer"); // element to have countdown written to
  setTimeout(tick, delay);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer"></div>
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robbiemcmullen/cer8qemt/1/

Comment: Use `setInterval`

Comment: Why `toFixed` ?!

Comment: @anthony why?!?!

Comment: I was having issues with setTimeout on its own so wanted to use window.performace, so input the toFixed to check if working

Comment: Yup thats right, as `setTimeout` is not precise while `performance.now` is.

Comment: But you're not using `performance.now` with the `setTimeout` (or setInterval) - the `setTimeout` is always 20ms (or thereabouts as not 100% accurate).

Comment: I seem to recall that `setTimeout` is based on when something ends vs `setInterval` is based on when it begins (something like that). Plus it's more appropriate for looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the precision is not the same for minutes and seconds.

You need to round to the nearest second before `/60` / `%60`.

Consider: exactly 9 mins remaining:

```
var x = 540; 
console.log(x.toFixed() % 60, Math.floor(x / 60));`
```

Output is: (0,9)

Then consider the call 20 ms later:

```
var x = 539.980; 
console.log(x.toFixed() % 60, Math.floor(x / 60));
```

the output is now: (0, 8).

So the seconds haven't changed (yet) but the minute does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using setInterval and removing the use of .toFixed ()
Why do you use an interval of 20ms and not 1 second?

```js
//method for countdown timer
$(document).ready(function() {

  function now() {
      return window.performance ? window.performance.now() : Date.now();
  }

  function tick() {
      var timeRemaining = countdown - elapsedTime;
      var countdownMinutes = Math.floor(timeRemaining / 60);
      var countdownSeconds = timeRemaining % 60;

      countdownTimer.innerHTML = countdownMinutes + ":" + countdownSeconds;

      if (countdownSeconds < 10) {
        countdownTimer.innerHTML = countdownMinutes + ":" + 0 + countdownSeconds;
      }
      ++elapsedTime;

      return timeRemaining;
  }

      var countdown = 600;
      var elapsedTime = 0;
      var timeRemaining;
      // countdown: time in seconds until user may login again
      //var delay = 20;
      // delay: time (in ms) per tick
      var initTick = now(); // initTick: timestamp (in ms) when script is initialized
      var countdownTimer = document.querySelector(".timer");
      // countdownTimer: element to have countdown written to
      var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(tick() <= 0) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer"></div>
```

js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ud3wm8t1/